# Oil pressure dropped wont start

Tags: engine, starting, oil, buick, lesabre

95 Buick Lesabre- 70’s miles. Hasnt been driving as clean for last couple weeks and few days ago it was overheating and pulled over and added water. Cooled down then about 15 minutes later I noticed oil pressure going low until it dropped and car died and left me stranded. Wont start. Appears to crank on just wont start. Check engine codes indicate both o2 sensors but that seems odd to me. (Not knowledgeable at all by the way) any suggestions what to look at would be greatZ